# A neural network that can't overfit?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am fitting a model to some noisy satellite data.  The labels are measurements of rock on the bars of a river. There is a noisy but significant relationship.  I only have 250 points but the method would expand and eventually run off much bigger datasets.  I'm looking at a mix of models (RANSAC, Huber, SVM Regression) and DNNs.  My DNN results seem too good to be true.  The network looks like:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, kernel_regularizer= regularizers.l2(0.001), input_dim=NetworkDims, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(128, kernel_regularizer= regularizers.l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, kernel_regularizer= regularizers.l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, kernel_regularizer= regularizers.l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(32, kernel_regularizer= regularizers.l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
        # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

And when I save the history and plot training loss (green dots) and validation loss (cyan line) vs epoch I get this:

[image: Loss vs Epoch]

Training and validation loss just creep down.  With a small dataset, I was expecting the validation loss to go its own way.  In fact, if I run a 10-fold cross val score with this network, the error reported by cross val score does creep down.  This just looks too good to be true.  It implies that I could train this thing for 1000 epochs and still improve results.  If it looks too good to be true, it usually is, but why?

EDIT: More results.

So I tried to cut dropout to 0.1 at each and remove the L2.  Inteesting.  With the toned-down drop-out, I get even better results:

[10% dropout rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hto8W.png)

Without the L2, there is overfitting:
[No L2 reg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljoqg.png)

Comment: How does the loss of your DNN compare to the other methods? You could try removing all the regularization to check if you can overfit on the training data. If not, something could be wrong. Are your training and validation data overlapping, for instance?

Comment: You could try to gather a few more examples that were never involved anywhere and make some predictions to check it....

Comment: I can think of two cases where such a result is possible: 1. Your validation and training data set somehow overlaps. 2. The loss of ca. 0.075 is quite bad for your case and you actually need much more time for training.

Comment: how do you scale your data? Do you transform it all together and then split into train/validation?

Comment: The errors are actually comparable to am SVM regression output. And I use a standard scaler on an array of all the samples before I run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you have such a high dropout on every layer, which is why it's having trouble just overfitting on the training data. My prediction is that if you lower that dropout and regularization, it'll learn the training data much faster.

I'm not too sure if the results are too good to be true because it's hard to base how good a model is based on loss function.  But it should be the dropout and regularization that is preventing it from overfitting in a few epochs.

Comment: So if you see above, I tried that.  Indeed the removal of regularisation allowed the model to overfit.  Reducing the dropout rate made the model fit better. So is this a good sign?  I context of the work, the results of the DNN are really interesting and fir a pattern with the other ML methods.  I just want to b sure I'm not interpreting noisy or numeric fantasy.  But there is a ruther tst coming that will check if the DNN can replicate known patterns in nature.  Guess I'll know then. Thanks